# Is this a sign of virus attack on my computer?

Tags: crash, virus, malware

I have a PC at home running on Windows 7, 32-bit.

Recently, when clearing the temp folder (accessible by pressing %temp% on the Run command), I found that the folder has got some foul videos downloaded from Internet. By foul, I mean totally disgusting, of a very, very, very low level (like pornographic, horrible scenes, etc. which I can't mention). This has been occurring quite often. They come after some days even if I delete them.

I have a licensed copy of QuickHeal in my computer, and a full system scan at great depths shows that there is no virus, malware or any other system change. Behaviour Detection is set to highest security. Firewall is also on.

Our computer is accessed only by my father and me. We never visit any foul site, not even Facebook or Twitter or Google Plus. My father visits a travel forum, while I mostly use it for Java programming.

Moreover, the computer has recently started to crash frequently. We've called a mechanic, who could find no error. The computer has got 4GB RAM, yet sometimes everything on the screen freezes and then everything crashes, including Windows. The task bar and start button are not accessible, and mostly we have to power off the computer and reboot it.

The files come only if **connected to Internet**. We've tested, and not connected the PC to Internet for a month, and no videos had come.

We work on either Opera browser or Chrome. Both these browsers are known for protecting users from malicious sites. We've installed anti-tracking extensions to browsers like [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com) to prevent tracking.

So, why are these videos coming? I feel somebody is bypassing QuickHeal security firewall and accessing the computer. I conduct a full system scan and a backup every week, so I'm not greatly worried for files, but what is it? What can I do to prevent this? How can I know who is accessing the computer by hacking firewall?

*N.B.: somebody wanted to mark this as a duplicate to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) one. Let me explain the difference. I don't even know till now whether the computer has been hacked or its a virus. Until and unless I'm confirmed it's a virus, it's not a duplicate.*

Comment: It is more likely to be someone with local access to the PC. Check the event log to make sure that you know when the Pc has been used and see if the file creation times match up with one of you logging in. You might not like to consider it but if you know that it is not you then there is a reasonable chance that it might actually be the other user.

Comment: @Mokubai event logs say that they were created both at times when I was using the computer, or father was using it. Moreover, the files come only if I connect to Internet. We've tested, and not connected the PC to Internet for a month, and no videos had come.

Comment: When you find the files, can you go into their properties and see what user owns them?

Comment: The sysinternals suite has diskmon and sysmon, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/. Diskmon will show all processes that access the particular folder and log the activity (you might need procmon, last time I did something like this it was filemon), you'll need to filter heavily. Sysmon can show all the internet activity. The file metadata might give clues too; was anyone in the house when the files were created (this data can be spoofed easily, it's just an indication).

Comment: @K.A we work on administrator account, without any other account. So only admin owns them.

Comment: @WrichikBasu not only would separate user accounts be better for security, it would help you find out if this problem is specific to one particular user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is my computer compromised?*

This can be a rather broad question. I think there are a few things you need to look into before isolating the issue. Firstly, run `shell:startup` and see if any odd links exist, and  then check the `startup` tab of Task Manager (`taskmgr.exe`) to see if something is running.

The next step is to [view the running processes on your PC](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001111.htm). Ones that should stick out are:

- Odd names, seemingly jumbled letters;
- Processes with no description

A good way to see what network connections are running (if a virus is downloading a payload) is to run `netstat -ab` and see the connections.

If the process only starts when you connect to the internet (which it sounds like), then perhaps manually compare the files by running this **before and after** you're on the net:

`tasklist.exe | out-file C:\tmp\before.txt` and naming the next one as `after.txt`, see what you've got running, and any variances you're unsure of, simply "Google" (I love how we've coined that services name) it.

Now, it's time to [boot into safe mode with networking](https://community.shaw.ca/docs/DOC-1017) and run the following in administrative shells:

`sfc.exe /scannow`, `chkdsk /f` and a memory test; not entirely relevant, but useful nonetheless.

Whilst in here, if you're on Windows 7 (which was stated), I would recommend you download two things to run:

- [Combofix](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) and;
- [Avira CLI](https://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-command-line-scanner-scancl)

Run a scan with these and see if anything is identified. Before rebooting into your PC, remove administrative functions from your account (whilst making another account with admin rights), to see if you get violation errors with process trying to perform tasks unintended.

Lastly, convert to Linux ;)

Comment: Last is not possible. Other I'll try today evening, after I return home.

Comment: @Wrichik how did you go?

Comment: Every time I switch on the computer, I'm switching on netstat. I'll keep on doing that for some more days, because I haven't found anything suspicious till date, nor have the videos come again. If they come again, I'll try out all the other methods you've said.

Comment: @WrichikBasu - well?

Comment: Both father and I have been keeping a close watch. We've found one unknown process that is accessing the Internet. We could detect it and block it. That was about three days ago. No videos have come till now again. So I'm accepting thy answer.

Comment: Again the videos came, but now I'm unable to see anything with netstat -ab. It says "The requested operation requires elevation."

Comment: @Wrichik you just run the shell as admin  (right click --> run as admin)

Answer (score 0):

First, a review of [QuickHeal](https://www.pcmag.com/review/349140/quick-heal-internet-security-17) shows some issues, though any antt-malware (antivirus) tool may miss some items. Try a scan with another product, such as the free versions of [Kaspersky Virus Scan](https://usa.kaspersky.com/free-virus-scan) or [Avira Rescue System](https://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system).

The best way to check and remove malware is by booting from external media or USB stick, rather than the PC's internal drive. [There are a number of capable bootable tools](https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785), such as the Avira one above.

Remove any questionable browser extension, or simply uninstall the browser and reinstall afresh.

Another likelihood, though, is that someone has access to your PC, either physically in your home or over WiFi. Disable [Remote Access](https://www.lifewire.com/disable-windows-remote-desktop-153337), disable sharing of your hard drive, except for those folders you want others to access. [Maximize router security with WPA2 and hidden SSID.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/hide-wifi-network-prevent-detected/) Change passwords on the router and on all PC's, and use upper and lower case letter, typographical symbols and numbers.

Comment: I've scanned with Kaspersky Virus Scan, but as we already have a paid version of QuickHeal, father didn't buy it and I tried on the free trial version. Secondly, remote access was never switched on; sharing is strictly off; and there is no WiFi router as the broadband is connected to computer via optical fibre cable.

Comment: My answer builds off this; extension removal, removal of shares and new passwords/SSIDs.

Comment: @WrichikBasu, does the broadband device have WiFi, even though your PC is connected directly? An intruder could access it even though *you* are  not using it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it goes from our house to the local distribution centre via cable. There is no option for WiFi near our house. Our connection in the house has no WiFi facility. The network gateways are all connected through cable. I don't know how it is connected to the regional centre. I think via cable, but cannot assure.